# Probability of die throws and choosing points from a square

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a square with vertices $(0,0), (0,2), (2,0)$ and $(2,2)$. Five points are independently and randomly chosen from the square. If a point $(x,y)$ satisfies $x+2y \le 2$, then a pair of dice are rolled. Otherwise, a single die is rolled. Let $N$ be the total number of dice rolled. For $5 \le n \le 10$, the probability that $N = n$ is?

The answer is $\binom{5}{n-5} (1/4)^{n-5}(3/4)^{10-n}$

I could decipher the fact that the distribution of the die has probability as $3/4$ and $1/4$ for a single die roll and two die rolls respectively. I can't proceed further, can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$n_1$ be the number of single die rolls and $n_2$ be the number of double die roll, then, $n_1+n_2 = 5$ and $n_1 + 2n_2 = n$. And use binomial distribution.

Values of $n_1$ and $n_2$ in the form of $n$ are,

> $$n_2 = n-5 \text{ and } n_1 = 10 - n$$

$P(N=n)$ using binomial distribution is,

> $$P(N=n) = \binom{5}{n_1} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n_1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{5-n_1} = \binom{5}{10-n}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{10-n}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-5}$$

Note that,

> $$\binom{5}{10-n} = \binom{5}{5-(10-n)} = \binom{5}{n-5}$$

Comment: Thank you for that neat solution expiTTpi1z0